# BeginStorybard on DataTrigger WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datatrigger, wpf-animation

I am using a transition animation for when my application boots up.

```
<Storyboard x:Key="InTransition">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="0"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05.5000000" Value="1"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)">
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="-72"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:05" Value="-157"/>
                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0,0.5,1" KeyTime="00:00:05.5000000" Value="0"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

This works well if I start it as an `EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"` But  I want to bind it to a property on my viewModel called `IsInitialized`. Problem is `Windows.Triggers` doesn't allow `DataTrigger`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that you cannot use a `DataTrigger` in your `Triggers` collection. Instead, you need to use the `UIElement.Style.Triggers` collection. Then you can use the `DataTrigger.EnterActions` element to host your `Storyboard` element:

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourProperty}" Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard ... />
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
</Window>
```

Comment: I've tried that but my animation contains `Storyboard.TargetName` properties which when using style throws an exception `A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName. Remove TargetName`. I don't think I can remove the TargetName as my storyboard animates numerous elements ...

Comment: You put your `Storyboard` in the wrong `Style`... move it to the element that you previously referenced in the `Storyboard.TargetName` property instead.