# WPF, How can i start StoryBoard by property change

Tags: wpf, xaml

---

I'm trying to start a StoryBoard using a PropertyChange. The goal is to animate the background when the property changes.

The question is, how do I bind the property to the EventTrigger?

---

```
<Label>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Label}}" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="BackgroundBorder" Background="{DynamicResource EfoGreen}" />
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="????????????">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                    Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBorder"
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                    From="0"
                                                    To="1"
                                                    Duration="0:0:2">
                                        </DoubleAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

I'm trying to start a StoryBoard using a PropertyChange. The goal is to animate the background when the property changes.

The question is, how do I bind the property to the EventTrigger?

Comment: You would use a DataTrigger as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22409730/1136211).

Comment: As the name suggests, EventTrigger is a trigger that is triggered by an event. DataTrigger (and Trigger)  are triggered by data (property values). Microsoft learn: [How to: Trigger an Animation When a Property Value Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-trigger-an-animation-when-a-property-value-changes?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)